# Where is jenkins document of agent kubernetes section?

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I want to know if there are any other parameters for `agent kubernetes` field in declarative pipelines ,
There is only `defaultContainer` and `yaml` in [official document](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent). And no information at [official kubernetes plugin github](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin)

But I think there are other parameters like `cloud` or `idleMinutes`, where can I find related documents?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe is described at [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/master/README.md#pod-template).

All properties of `Pod template` can act as a parameters in `agent kubernetes`